# How do I print specific strings from text files?

Tags: python, string, find, range, concatenation

```
file_contents = x.read() 
#print (file_contents)
for line in file_contents:
     if "ase" in line:
         print (line)
```

I'm looking for all the sentences that contain the phrase "ase" in the file. When I run it, nothing is printed.

Comment: format code as code. It's a single click.

Comment: As you'd find pretty quickly with e.g. `print(line)` *outside* the condition, you're currently looping over **individual characters**, which obviously cannot contain a string of three characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `file_contents` is the result of `x.read()`, it's a *string* not a list of strings.
So you're iterating on each character.

Do that instead:

```
file_contents = x.readlines()
```

now you can search in your lines

or if you're not planning to reuse `file_contents`, iterate on the file handle with:

```
for line in x:
```

so you don't have to `readlines()` and store all file in memory (if it's big, it can make a difference)

Comment: Thanks! Whats the difference between a line and a sentence?

Comment: @NickRizzolo there isn't a difference if each sentence is on a line. Else, there _is_ a difference...

Answer (score 1):

`read` will return the whole content of the file (not line by line) as string. So when you iterate over it you iterate over the single characters:

```
file_contents = """There is a ase."""
for char in file_contents:
    print(char)
```

You can simply iterate over the file object (which returns it line-by-line):

```
for line in x:
    if "ase" in line:
        print(line)
```

Note that if you actually look for sentences instead of lines where `'ase'` is contained it will be a bit more complicated. For example you could `read` the complete file and split at `.`:

```
for sentence in x.read().split('.'):
    if "ase" in sentence:
        print(sentence)
```

However that would fail if there are `.`s that don't represent the end of a sentence (like abbreviations).

Comment: Yes it is. What does a line mean? The program returned paragraphs of varying lengths.

Comment: Roughly: A line is terminated by a "newline" character (for example if you hit "enter" in a text document). A sentence is usually terminated by a `.`.

Comment: @NickRizzolo Have you tried the last mentioned approach from my answer?

Comment: I need codecs to read the x file and readlines is not an attribute of codecs. x = codecs.open('/Users/name/Desktop/CommercialArticles/3_Biotech/3_Biotech#1.txt', 'r', 'utf-8')

Comment: @NickRizzolo I never used `readlines` in the answer. Or do I just misunderstand your question?

Comment: I entered your last part verbatim and nothing printed